# Woocommerce get Shipping Zone

Tags: woocommerce

Does anyone know how to get the shipping zone from woocommerce?
I think this comes from the table rate shipping extension but has now been added to WC core.

I'm guessing it's similar to

`WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();`

Thanks!

Comment: The most changed part in WC is shipping within major version 2.6. Here you can find all the details: https://woocommerce.wordpress.com

Answer (score 11):

You can easily get the shipping zones by following given code

```
$delivery_zones = WC_Shipping_Zones::get_zones();

foreach ((array) $delivery_zones as $key => $the_zone ) {

  echo $the_zone['zone_name'];

}
```

It will return the zone information for each zone.